# An array that increases in size as a loop continues C

Tags: arrays, pointers, dynamic, linked-list, malloc

I'm trying to generate an array that increases in size as a while loop iterates. I know a pointer has something to do with the solution. Please look at the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

  int x = 0;
  int *F = malloc(sizeof(int)); //I want F to start out as :- 
  F[0] = 1;                     // 1 by 1
  F[1] = 2;                     // 1 by 2 such that it increases in size when assigned
  int now = 2;

  int evenSum = 2;

  while (x <= 40000) {


    F[now] = F[now-1] + F[now-2];
    x = F[now];

    if (F[now] % 2)
    {
        evenSum += F[now];
    }

    ++now;
  }

  printf("The outcome is %d\n", evenSum);

  //free(F);
  // Yes this is problem 2 of euler challenge, i already got a working static model

}
```

Many Thanks in Advance

**EDIT**
What I'm actually looking for is the sum of all the even fib's up to a cut off limit of 40M. I could (what i did first time) sum the even numbers as i encounter them during the fib sequence. This meant i did not keep a array of some arbitary size. The purpose of this post is to create a growing memory that just keeps on consuming memory until it gets to the answer.
The following is the code I got from the brilliant answer that was given.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct vector {
    size_t size;
    int *data;
};

void vector_resize(struct vector *vector, size_t size) {
    if (vector->size >= size)
        return;
    while (vector->size < size)
        vector->size *= 2;
    vector->data = realloc(vector->data, sizeof(int) * vector->size);
    assert(vector->data != NULL);
}

struct vector * vector_init() {
    struct vector *vector = malloc(sizeof(*vector));
    vector->size = 4;
    vector->data = malloc(vector->size * sizeof(int));
    return vector;
}

void vector_free(struct vector *vector) {
    free(vector->data);
    free(vector);
}

void vector_put(struct vector *vector, size_t index, int data) {
    vector_resize(vector, index+1);
    vector->data[index] = data;;
}

int vector_get(struct vector *vector, size_t index) {
    vector_resize(vector, index+1);
    return vector->data[index];
}

int main() {
    struct vector *vector = vector_init();

    int fibNow = 0;

    int now = 2;
    vector_put(vector, 0, 1);
    vector_put(vector, 1, 2);

    int evenSum = 2;

    while (fibNow <= 4000000) {
        fibNow = vector_get(vector, (now-1)) + vector_get(vector, (now-2));
        vector_put(vector, now, fibNow);

        if (fibNow % 2 == 0) {
            evenSum += fibNow;
        }

        ++now;
    }
    printf("The outcome is %d\n", evenSum);

    // vector_put(vector, 0, 5);
    // vector_put(vector, 9, 2);
    // int i;
    // for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
    //     printf("index 0: %d\n", vector_get(vector, i));
    vector_free(vector);
}
```

Comment: You can allocate an array on the heap with `malloc(sizeof(int) * NUMELEMENTS)`. Check out `realloc` to reallocate enough space for your expanding array.

Comment: Use `realloc`, though in this case you might as well just allocate the entire array at one go and save yourself the headache (or even better, use just a few `int`s since you only need to track no more than three numbers in the sequence and the current sum at any given time).

Comment: I want the complete list of fib numbers in memory, so i can manipulate them at a later date.

The evenSum for fib numbers under 40K is generated on the fly & i have no desire to store that.

Comment: regarding this code:   int *F = malloc(sizeof(int)); //I want F to start out as :- 
  F[0] = 1;                     // 1 by 1
  F[1] = 2;   Since the code is only malloc'ing a single area for an int, the f[1] is corrupting the heap (where the malloc allocated its' area from.  Therefore, the code action is undefined at 'F[1] = 2' and any action after that is only a matter of luck.  Suggest, as an initial fix, to malloc enough space for at least 3 int's I.E.  int *F = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);

Comment: this line: ++now; results in the line: F[now] = F[now-1] + F[now-2]; progressively corrupting more and more of the heap.

Comment: this code:   if (F[now] % 2)
    {
        evenSum += F[now];
    } has the 'if' block skipped when the result of the modulo operation is 0, however, the variable naming indicates the sum should only be done when the result of the modulo is 0, so, the 'if' is not correct.

Comment: BTW: you could initially only allocate a 3 int sized area.  then in the for loop, insert the following code.  F[0] = F[1]; F[1] = F[2]; and never increment the value of 'now'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, In C we aren't allowed to overload the `operator[]`. But we could still create an object that functions like your request:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct vector {
    size_t size;
    int *data;
};

void vector_resize(struct vector *vector, size_t size) {
    if (vector->size >= size)
        return;
    while (vector->size < size)
        vector->size *= 2;
    vector->data = realloc(vector->data, sizeof(int) * vector->size);
    assert(vector->data != NULL);
}

struct vector * vector_init() {
    struct vector *vector = malloc(sizeof(*vector));
    vector->size = 4;
    vector->data = malloc(vector->size * sizeof(int));
    return vector;
}

void vector_free(struct vector *vector) {
    free(vector->data);
    free(vector);
}

void vector_put(struct vector *vector, size_t index, int data) {
    vector_resize(vector, index+1);
    vector->data[index] = data;;
}

int vector_get(struct vector *vector, size_t index) {
    vector_resize(vector, index+1);
    return vector->data[index];
}

int main() {
    struct vector *vector = vector_init();

    vector_put(vector, 0, 5);
    vector_put(vector, 9, 2);

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        printf("index 0: %d\n", vector_get(vector, i));

    vector_free(vector);
}
```

Additionally, it's fun to look at a C++ version of what this could be. C++ makes this look far more like your original code, because we can overload operator[] for arbitrary objects.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class auto_growing_vector {
    private:
        std::vector<T> data;

    public:
        T & operator[](size_t index) {
            if (index >= data.size())
                data.resize(index + 1);
            return data[index];
        }
};

int main() {
    auto_growing_vector<int> vector;

    vector[0] = 5;
    vector[9] = 2;

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        printf("index 0: %d\n", vector[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to overload the [] operator to do this? In C it is allowed to use a[i], where the 'a' is an arbitary type pointer to an arbitary memory location, and 'i' an integer which offsets location for  i*sizeof(type of the pointer)
So a[i] <=> *(a+i) Thanks :)

Comment: @ETFovac: I'm sorry, I'm not able to understand your question. Note that in the C code, `vector_put()` does more than just `return data[i]` and in the C++ code, `operator[]()` also does more than just `return data[i]`. Additionally, note that `auto_growing_vector ` is a C++ object, not an array.

Comment: @ETFovac OP specified that he wants `a[i]` to realloc `a` so that it `a[i]` is not an out-of-bounds access

Comment: I have misunderstood what you've said. It's OK now. :)

Comment: This is exactly What I wanted, also known as **Linked Lists**

Comment: @WesleyTaylor: This is __not__ a linked list. This is a vector. They have different properties. It is very expensive to do random lookup in a linked list.

Answer (score 2):

In general, `realloc` should do the trick for you. Example (this is just a snippet - you will need to do the rest yourself):

```
int *F;
F = malloc(2 * sizeof *F); // note you have to start with 2 elements for your code, not 1
F[0] = 1;
F[1] = 2;
// when you know you need to increase the size of F:
temp = realloc(F, n * sizeof *F); // where n is the new size in elements
if(temp != NULL) F = temp; // note that the block may have moved to a new place!
else {
  printf("unable to grow the array to %d elements!\n", n);
  free(F);
  exit(0);
}
```

Of course for this problem you don't need to keep all the Fibonacci numbers - just the last two. This actually suggests a much simpler code. Let me start if for you, and see if you can finish it (since you are doing the Euler problems, which are all about figuring it out for yourself):

```
int first = 1;
int second = 1; // usually you start with 1,1,2,3,...
int temp, current;
int count;
int N = 4000; // where we stop

for(count = 2; count < N; count ++) {
  current = first + second;
  first = second;
  second = current;
}
```

If you look closely, you can get even more efficient that this (hint, you really only need to keep one older value, not two...)

Reading the comments, if you want all the numbers in memory, you should just allocate enough space from the outset:

```
F = malloc(4000 * sizeof *F);
```

and no further manipulations are needed. Make sure your last index is 3999 in that case (since arrays are zero indexed).

Comment: I have a working static model, the whole purpose of this experimentation was to create a function that just keeps on churning over until the while statement has been met.

I take it that with regards to efficiency what your hinting at is something along the lines of
`current = current + previous; previous = current - previous;`

Comment: I see that now - you are not looking for the nth Fib number, but the first one greater than something. You can in fact get a good approximation of the size of a Fibonacci number from F(n) ~ phi^n / sqrt(5) where phi = 1.618033... so to get a Fibonacci number greater than N you need to allocate about log(sqrt(5)*N)/log(phi) elements. Throw in an extra 10 for good measure and you're almost certainly good.

Comment: I did not know that was the mathematical hack. Thank you for showing me.
What I'm actually looking for is the sum of all the even fib's up to a cut off limit of 40K.

I could (what i did first time) sum the even numbers as i encounter them during the fib sequence. This meant i did not keep a array of some arbitary size.
The purpose of this post is to create a growing memory that just keeps on consuming memory until it gets to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I One way would be to use 2D array int[n][n], whith a lot of unused space

II Easier way would be to expend array size in every iteration by realocate function.
Just in that case, either:

a) every element of the original array would be a pointer to a new array of length i (i beeing iteration number), you would then realocate the original array to make size for new pointer, then allocate  i*sizeof(int)  of new memory for that new array that pointer would point to.

b) You would make linearized traingular matrix in which the original array will hold just numbers, not pointers. In every iteration you would expand it's size for i new elements. Linearized trangular matrix is a onedimensional array of numbers in which data is saved like this:

```
ordinary matrix: (/ = wasted memory)
A/// 
BC//
DEF/
GHIJ

linarized triangular matrix
ABCDEFGHIJ
```

You can acces linerized triangular matrix element E with coordinates [y,x] = [2,1] (element 'A' taken for origin) like

```
sum=0;
for(iy=0;iy<y;iy++)
  for(ix=0;ix<=y && ix<x;ix++) sum++;
//myLinMatr[sum]=='E'
```